# Java Converting Classes

Tags: java, dto

I have a class like:

```
Student
-name
-surname
-address
-number
```

and I have a DTO for it like:

```
StudentDTO
-name
-surname
-number
```

I will send my student class to another class just with name, surname and number fields(I mean not with all fields) and I decided to name it as DTO (I am not using serializing or etc. just I send this class's object as parameter to any other class's methods).

However lets assume that I have a line of code like that:

```
getAllStudents();
```

and it returns:

```
List<Student>
```

but I want to assign it to a variable that:

```
List<StudentDTO>
```

How can I convert them easily?

**PS:** I can't change my *getAllStudents();* method's inside. I have list of students and want a fast and well-designed way to convert a list of objects into another list of objects.

Comment: Don't bother using the getAllStudents() method then. Take your list, and throw it into another method you *can* modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public StudentDTO convert() {
    StudentDTO newDTO = new StudentDTO(name, surname, number);
    return newDTO;
}
```

And you can implement this as a public method.

This, obviously, would be abstracted out into a larger convert method that could do batch processing. Another alternative would be to implement Cloneable and create a specific implementation just for Student -> StudentDTO.

Iterative example:

```
List<StudentDTO> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Student s : collection) {
        myList.add(s.convert());
    }
    return myList;
```

Comment: Is it a good idea for Student to know about StudentDTO?  I tend to use a `Converter<FROM, TO>` interface in cases where I need to convert beans.  That also gives you the option of using a functional style to apply the converter to each list element.

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache commons-beanutils:

```
PropertyUtils.copyProperties(studentDtoBean, studentBean);
```

Comment: While it's simple, I don't think introducing dependencies is worth it.

Comment: @DavidB  I think that commons-beanutils is present in most applications because is used by many open-source libraries so, probably, this dependency is already present.

Answer (score 0):

You can extends Student from StudentDTO:

```
public class StudentDTO {
    name;
    surname;
    number;
}

public class Student extends StudentDTO {
    address;
}
```

Than you can do:

```
List<StudentDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<StudentDTO>(getAllStudents());
```

Comment: Even if `Student` extends `StudentDTO`, you can't convert `List<Student>` to `List<StudentDTO>` implicitly

Comment: You don't have to change your getAllStudents(); method

Comment: Have you at least tried to do something like `List<StudentDTO> lsDTO; List<Student> ls;= new ArrayList<Student>(); lsDTO = ls;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the `StudentDTO` to extend `Student`

```
public StudentDTO extends Student {
}
```

Remember that you could have the `address` attribute but no need to use it. If you can do it, then just change the result of your method to:

```
public List<? extends Student> getAllStudents() {
    List<StudentDTO> lsStudentDTO = new ArrayList<StudentDTO>();
    //fill the list...
    return lsStudentDTO;
}
```

EDIT:

You're not changing the code inside, you're changing the method definition :). Also, you can always extend the methods, maybe to something like

```
public List<? extends Student> getAllStudentsDTO() {
    //maybe you should add another logic here...
    return getAllStudents();
}
```

If you can't even change this behavior, just go with @DavidB answer.

Comment: Nice approach. However I have edited my question, I cant change the code inside that method.

Comment: I get all students from a service class and it's interface definition is List<Student>. Changing the method definition is not a problem but I have many other different classes (as like manager, lecturer, etc.) and it will not easy to change all the method definitions.

Comment: You must have say that from the beginning. If it comes from a service, then just go with @DavidB answer, you need another class that converts the `List<Student>` to `List<StudentDTO>` and viceversa.