# How to follow the code with Primefaces datatable and see other datatable?

Tags: hibernate, primefaces, datatable

I'm newbie with hibernate, Primefaces and JSF. I have a problem that I don´t know how to continue the code.
I have a database with firebird in a computer, and i connect with jdbc.properties and show it in a datatable with primefaces in index.xhtml . It works.
I have EmpBean.java, Empresa.java, EmpresaDAO.java, EmpresaService.java.
Now I want to select a row in a datatable and when I push the button goes to other web with other datatable and data. It´s called Ldiario. I have in hibernate ManyToOne and OneToMany in Empresa.java and Ldiario.java but how I can access to data of Ldiario, I have to make LdiarioDAO, LDIarioService or It´s not necessary?

**Empresa.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresas")
public class Empresa implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa")  
private Set<Ldiario> ldiarios;
```

**Ldiario.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LDIARIO2014")
public class Ldiario implements Serializable{


@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;  

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn (name = "clave_id") 
private Empresa empresa;
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:head>
      <title>Lista con Java Server Faces</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body> 

      <h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="radioDT"  var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
                selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">



    <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="Id">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="AÑO">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
       </p:column>

       <!-- "#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" -->
<f:facet name="footer">

    <p:commandButton action="#{empresaBean.View}" value="Seleccionar" title="Ir Menu" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}" >
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empresaBean.empresa}" value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" />
</p:commandButton>

    <p:commandButton process="radioDT" update=":form:displaySingle"  icon="ui-icon-search" value="View"  oncomplete="PF('empresaDialog').show()" />
.
.
.
```

**diario.xhtml**

```
 <p:dataTable   var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
                selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">
```

if I have empresaBean.getEmpresaList () in the second database could access data Ldiario? How?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem closely related to Primefaces, you should review your architecture.

You should put in the middle another tier and convert your hibernate data model (DAO) to DTO (Data Transfer Object) in your controller tier (we talk about M V C pattern). See more on [Java Converting Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785919/java-converting-classes). 
It's not a good practice show your DAO directly to view layer and make operations on it.
As opposed to DAO, DTO are lightweight object that implements java.io.Serializable that contains only getter and setter and they don't contain any logic and they are perfect to carry data.

In this way, it is not important where database is, database could be not exists. Or you could decide to change it with a another data provider such as web service, xml or NOSQL DB without change nothing on view layer. Each DTO object can be composed from data coming from different data source.